# Android default media player

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I want to know how a default media player works.Like how it scans all songs in sd card,how it displays them,so overall entire working on default media player.
I want this information so that I can compare it with my custom media player and check how fast my media player is working as compared to default one.I have tried searching internet but was not able to find some relevant information related to this.

Comment: I don't know anything specific to Android but if you are looking for something for any kind of media player check [this article](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/streaming-video-and-audio.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link but unfortunately I am looking for android based only.

Comment: You may download Android source code here - https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html and compare your media player with default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad in perspective and hence, I will refer you to corresponding paths to get an understanding of the overall system.

First, the overall processing of `media files` starts from the `Gallery` application. Though not the entry point, [`ImageCacheRequest`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Gallery2/src/com/android/gallery3d/data/ImageCacheRequest.java#46) could be a good reference point to start the study, which shows how a cached image is read and rendered onto the screen.

Next, to understand how this thumbnail is generated, you will have to refer to [`ThumbnailManager.java`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Camera/src/com/android/camera/Thumbnail.java) which is invoked from `camera`, `mms` etc.

`Thumbnail` class internally employs [`MediaMetadataRetriever`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.java) which is the main class for retrieving the thumbnail data.

`MediaMetadataRetriever` has a corresponding `JNI` implementation as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaMetadataRetriever.cpp). The main function of interest is `getFrameAtTime`.

The most common implementation is [`StagefrightMetadataRetriever`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/StagefrightMetadataRetriever.cpp), which works on a simple principle. First, a `MediaExtractor` i.e. a parser is created which will *sniff* out the media-file type and create a corresponding parser entity as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/StagefrightMetadataRetriever.cpp#321). Next, the parser will then invoke a codec to decode the corresponding **key frame** at the requested time stamp and provide the image back as can be observed in [`extractVideoFramewithFlags`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/StagefrightMetadataRetriever.cpp#extractVideoFrameWithCodecFlags).

Inside this function, a [codec is created](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/StagefrightMetadataRetriever.cpp#156), frame is decoded, color converted and returned back to the caller which will transfer the same to the higher application.

In a nutshell, I feel your player will not come into picture and as long as the corresponding parsers and codecs are registered with the system, the thumbnails will be generated .

Comment: +1 for the easy to understand explanation! I also learned that when I analyzed the android source code.

Comment: @artsylar. Thanks for the kind words

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how a default media player works

There are dozens of "default media player" applications, as different Android devices ship with different "media player" applications, frequently written by their device manufacturers.

You are welcome to take a look at [the implementation of the AOSP Music app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music), and there may be other open source media players that you can examine as well.